# How to resize nestedlinearlayout in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to resize layout(l2) which is already in other layout(l1).Please let me know how to achieve it.[image: Nested Layout]

I want to do it xml.I dont want hardcode dp values such as 50 dp for l1 and 30 dp2.

Generally we use width 0r height as 0 dp and layout weight to partition according to our requirement.Is there any similar way like it.

Comment: I tried giving android:layout_margin="25dp" ,it worked,Is this correct way?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is nested linearlayouts with transparent views inside them (they do not show anything, just take place); layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

is this ok?

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    ></RelativeLayout>
```